# How to Send DataTable over TCP server

Tags: c#, server

i have just recently created a TCP server in C# to handle all mySQL related queries instead of having them done on the client which could cause problems. Now the problem i am having is that when requesting for a specific query i would need to return the whole result back to the client which is stored as a DataTable. The problem i have is that i am unsure on how to convert the datatable into a byte to then be sent over to the network to the client.

I have tried to use a bitconverter but the method i have tried does not work.

Server

```
string Request = ReceiveData(client);

if (Request == "VendorInfo")
{
    DataTable VendorDetails = new DataTable();
    VendorDetails = FunctionToGetVendorInfo();
    byte[] ReturnTable = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(VendorDetails); //Cannot Convert DataTable into Bytes using this method
    client.Send(ReturnTable, 0, ReturnTable.Length, SocketFlags.None 
}
```

Client

```
byte[] messageFromServer = new byte[1024];
int size = ClientSocket.Receive(messageFromServer);

DataTable VendorInfo = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(messageFromServer, 0, size));
```

the client asks the server to run a SQL query which will return a large amount of rows from the database. The Server must then send the datatable it retrieved from the SQL query to the client.

Comment: Have you tried using protobuf?

Comment: Or JSON for that matter.

Comment: Also never use ASCII encoding, instead use UTF8. The former is a 7-bit encoding which only covers 128 Unicode codepoints, UTF8 covers all 1,000,000 codepoints.

Comment: Agreed it would make sense to send the data in some sort of serialised, structured format such as JSON, XML, or even CSV. Much easier to parse and process than a stream of raw bytes. You could also consider using a more structured protocol on top of TCP e.g. HTTP, or something with WCF.

Comment: Google `Serialization in .NET`.

Comment: just spent the past hour learning Protobuf and it turns out that protobuf can't serialize DataTables

Comment: Never mind there was a different version for serializing and Deserializing DataTables called ProtoBuf.Data. @Mt.Schneiders Thank you for telling me about Protobuf it worked.